# Random to Multi-List Number from One List

Tags: list, random, numbers

I have an array:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

How can I randomize `arr[]` to multi-list with No Duplicates?

FROM

```
arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

TO

```
arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
arr2[] = {2, 1, 4, 3}
arr3[] = {3, 4, 1, 2}
arr4[] = {4, 3, 2, 1}
```

Comment: You need to give a few details. What language are you using? What is a multi-list?

Comment: lol -_-, i answered in java -_- duh!

Comment: btw. your e.g arrays have duplicates, lol

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is preferable to use a `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();
int randonint = arr.remove(random.nextint(arr.getSize()));
```

Every time this code is runned, it will grab a random int from the list `arr`, then you can add it to a different List/Array

So, if you want to take all values from one list, and randomly place them to 3 other lists, use the following code:

```
List<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> to1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> to2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> to3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    arr1.add(i);
}
for (int count = 0 ; count < arr1.size() ; count++) {
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int randomvalue = arr.remove(random.nextint(arr.getSize()));
    switch (random.nextInt(3)) {
        case 0:
            to1.add(randomvalue);
        case 1:
            to2.add(randomvalue);
        case 2:
            to2.add(randomvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need multi array or list (From arr[] to multi arr (arr1, arr2, arr3) with number no duplicates). D U understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void GenerateRandomArray()
{
    var inputArray = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    var outputArray = GetRandomArray(inputArray);
    PrintArray(outputArray);
}

private static void PrintArray(int[,] outputArray)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < outputArray.GetLength(0); i += 1)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < outputArray.GetLength(1); j += 1)
        {
            Console.Write(outputArray[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static int[,] GetRandomArray(int[] inputArray)
{
    var lengthOfArray = inputArray.Length;
    var outputArray = new int[lengthOfArray,lengthOfArray];
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++)
    {
        var counterShifter = i;
        for (var j = 0; j < lengthOfArray;j++)
        {
            outputArray[i, j] = inputArray[counterShifter];
            counterShifter = counterShifter + 1 < lengthOfArray 
                ? counterShifter + 1 :
                0;
        }
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```